# Merging Assemblies in .NET 4.7.2?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, .net-framework, .net-4.0

Quick question; I know I can merge things with .NET 4.0 and below with ILMerge, but how would I do so on .NET 4.7.2?

ILMerge is outdated, so it fails to merge my assemblies (I have a project, along with FlatUI.dll for a design. (Flat UI Obtained from here: https://github.com/skylerspark/WindowsFlat-Form-Data)

Ive heard you can take the raw C# from a .NET DLL and physically add it as a source in your project as a way to merge them. I only want this because I need to make a standalone EXE file.

Comment: I love how I ask these questions after searching days on end, and finally like hours after I ask, I find an answer on my own... like wth.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely documented this method here: https://skylerspark.github.io/Tutorials/MergingAssemblies

Its difficult to merge files on later .NET's because of the way these scripts are setup, but its very much possible.

I was notified and give a link to a very old post about 2 scripts that could assign a class to an Assembly "file stream" and could allow you to create hidden file streams that linked to embedded DLLs that were placed inside the EXE during compilation.

Basically you need these two scripts: [Program.cs](https://skylerspark.github.io/Tutorials/resources/Program.cs) (This Replaces the default Program.cs and the areas in the script that ask you to fill it in, well you need to fill it in or its useless.) and also [EmbeddedAssembly.cs](https://skylerspark.github.io/Tutorials/resources/EmbeddedAssembly.cs) (This makes a file stream that allows you to change your dll reference to a dll that was placed inside the project during compilation)

> Also if you just duplicate the resource1 class in Program.cs, you can add multiple hidden DLLs into the exe (Not recommended for performance reasons)

You need to add your DLL(s) as a reference, and add it to your project as an Existing File (It just goes into your projects main directory)

and finally (as shown in the documentation tutorial i made):

> Click on Your DLL(s) you put in references and change the setting “CopyLocal” to “false”.
>
> Next Click on the DLL(s) you added as just existing files, and change the setting “Build Action” to “Embedded Resource”

In the end this worked perfectly for me and I was able to successfully hide FlatUI.DLL into one single EXE and ran it on .NET 4.7.2 (latest stable .net)